# TypeScript how to use mapped type in module declaration?

Tags: typescript, module, typescript-generics

I need to create a type declaration for an external module. I need to create a mapped type for this declaration and failing to do so the module looks like

```
declare module "deferred-regl"{
  import { Regl } from 'regl'

  type IDregl<T> = {
    setRegl: (regl?: Regl) => void
    queue: any[]
    setQueue: (queuInput: any[]) => void
    (): IDregl<Regl>
    [K in keyof T]: () => <T[K]>
  };

  export default function defRegl(): IDregl<Regl>
}
```

It is failing on the `[K in keyof T]: () => <T[K]>` line
with errors:

```
Cannot find name 'K'. [2304]
Cannot find name 'keyof'. [2304]
```

and other syntax errors
I want to create a type that extends the Regl type with some new properties and methods. But also takes the existing keys on Regl and wraps them with functions
I previously was using an interface like

```
  export interface IDregl extends Regl{
    setRegl: (regl?: Regl) => void
    queue: any[]
    setQueue: (queuInput: any[]) => void
    (): IDregl
  }
```

But couldn't figure out how to annotate the Regl properties as functions and changed from interface to type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issued with this type definition.

- I belive you just cannot declare mapped type together with known properties in the same scope syntactically
- `() => <T[K]>` is not a valid type definition

I believe what you're looking for is something like:

```ts
declare module "deferred-regl"{
  import { Regl } from 'regl'

  type IDregl<T> = {
    setRegl: (regl?: Regl) => void
    queue: any[]
    setQueue: (queuInput: any[]) => void
    (): IDregl<Regl>
  } & {
    [K in keyof T]: () => T[K]
  };

  export default function defRegl(): IDregl<Regl>
}
```